# Combine merge sort and comb sort

Tags: c, sorting

I tried to combine comb sort and merge sort in C, so that merge sort wouldn't need to divide the sequence to the smallest unit (I mean when the length of the divisions in sequence less than a value called num, the program will immediately change to comb sort, and we can save time).

However, the code didn't work as I expected. (It should sort the sequence I gave to 12345678). I really don't know what is wrong with it. Please help me.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int i, int j, int *data){
     int attempt = data[i];
     data[i] = data[j];
     data[j] = attempt;
}

void comb(int n, int *data) {
    int i, gap = n, flag = 1;
    while (flag || gap > 1) {
        if ((gap = gap / 1.3) < 1) {
            gap = 1;
        }
        if (gap == 9 || gap == 10) {
            gap = 11;
        }
        flag = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < n - gap; i++) {
            if (data[i] > data[i + gap]) {
                swap(i, i + gap, data);
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
void merge(int first, int last, int min,int *data, int *work){

    int middle, mae, ato, i,j,k;

    if (abs(last - first) <= min) {
       int segment[last - first];
    for(k = first; k <= last; k++) {segment[k-first] = data[k];}
        comb(abs(last - first), segment);
    for(k = first; k <= last; k++) {data[k] = segment[k - first];}
    }
    else{
    middle = (first + last) / 2;
    merge(first, middle,min, data, work);
    merge(middle + 1, last,min, data, work);
    i = first;
    mae = first;
    ato = middle + 1;
    for(j = 0; j <= middle - first; j++) work[j] = data[j+first];
    while (mae <= middle && ato <= last) {
        if (work[mae-first] <= data[ato]) {
            data[i] = work[mae-first];
            i++;
            mae++;
        } else {
            data[i] = data[ato];
            i++;
            ato++;
        }
    }
    while (mae <= middle) {
        data[i] = work[mae-first];
        i++;
        mae++;
    }
    while (ato <= last) {
        data[i] = data[ato];
        i++;
        ato++;
    }
    }

}

int main(){
    int arr[8] = {2,8,7,3,6,1,5,4};
       int work[4] = {0,0,0,0};
    int i;  
    merge(0,7,2,arr,work);
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: your implementation of merge sort and comb sort is so convoluted... can you fix your code a little?

Comment: I haven't totally understood your code, but my guess is that you probably should change the sentence `comb(abs(last - first), segment)` to `comb(abs(last - first) + 1, segment)`. I assume that the `n` in your function `comb` means the length of the data, not the index of the last element.

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what you said. I have fixed it. :D